# Sieve of Eratosthenes Halting

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes via the Wikipedia page, for some reason this code halts and doesn't finish. I'm a beginner at C, so please explain If I misused anything.

I'm not sure, but am I misusing `sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define bool char
#define false 0
#define true 1

void sieveOfEratosthenes(const int until, int* primes);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    puts("sieveOfEratosthenes: 120");
    int* primes = malloc(sizeof(int));
    sieveOfEratosthenes(120, primes);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(primes) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf("%d:%d\n", i, primes[i]);
    }
}

void sieveOfEratosthenes(const int until, int* primes) {
    int numbers[until];
    for (int p = 2; p < until; p++) {
        numbers[p] = true;
    }

    int p = 2;
    while (true) {
        for (p = p * p; p < until; p += p) {
            numbers[p] = false;
        }
        for (int count = p; count < until; count++) {
            if (numbers[count] == true) {
                p = count;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p == until) {
            break;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < until; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == true) {
            primes = realloc(primes, (j + 1) * sizeof(int));
            primes[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: @undur_gongor I only allocate one int at first, and then in the function I allocate the rest using `realloc(primes, (j + 1) * sizeof(int))`.

Comment: I see. This will not work. `sizeof` does not "know" the number of primes you have found, it will just return the size of a pointer (e.g. 4 or 8). But this does not explain the observed behavior.

Comment: The pointer to the primes[] array is passed by value. If `thesieveOfEratosthenes()`  function realloc()s it, main still only has a pointer to the original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your routine:

```
void sieveOfEratosthenes(const int until, int* primes) {
    int numbers[until], count;
    for (int p = 2; p < until; p++) {
        numbers[p] = true;
    }

    int p = 2;
    while (true) {
        // You should not overwrite p since you later need it. 
        for (int i = p * p; i < until; i += p) {
            numbers[i] = false;
        }
        for (count = p + 1; count < until; count++) { // p+1 is the next prime candidate
            if (numbers[count] == true) {
                p = count;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count >= until) {  // You break when the loop above finishes
            break;
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < until; i++) {  // 2 is the first prime, not 0
        if (numbers[i] == true) {
            primes = realloc(primes, (j + 1) * sizeof(int));
            primes[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Apart from that, the `sizeof primes` approach does not work. You will have to hand back the number of found primes from your routine.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, the pseudo code starts at p^2

Comment: That is true. My bad. The lower multiples are already sorted out by the primes before.